# "Failed to connect" error when logging into system newly upgraded to 22.04.2

Tags: upgrade, login

I just successfully upgraded a system from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.2, and am getting the following error when logging in:

```
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
```

This error appears to be spurious, since once my login is complete I can open the problem URL with lynx, or use wget to retrieve the file meta-release-lts; nonetheless, it looks like the kind of error which might cause problems down the road and I'd like to correct it.

There are several posts here indicating that this, or a similar error occurred when *upgrading* from 20.04 to 22.04, but my upgrade went off without a hitch. I would just like to find the source of this error (which show up just before displaying /etc/motd).

This is basically a server installation of Ubuntu and has no GUI.